# Get full screen layout in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a main Activity, and I am loading Fragments inside it.
I do not want the ActionBar, so I have hidden it in Manifest as follows

```
android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
```

When I populate a Fragment, the ActionBar is hidden, but it gives a black portion on the bottom of the screen and I can't even use that specific portion in my layout.

Any help?

Comment: Can you show us your style.xml?

Comment: <style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"/>
@NougatLover

Comment: ok. Please replace that with this:   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>  and then android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project we are using that kind of style:

```
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` you set it like

```
<application ... 
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme">...
```

Comment: didn't get you @J.D.1731

Comment: it's more or less what @nougat-lover answered you, I would add only `android:windowActionBarOverlay` and you should see that your full screen layout is going to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your style.xml with below code:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar"> 
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> 
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> 
    </style>


</resources>
```

and then set theme as

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: Can you post fragment container xml?